# float list having gaps

Tags: css, css-selectors, html-lists

HTML

```
<ul>
<li>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog and the cat ran</li>
<li>sample 2</li>
<li>sample 3</li>
<li>sample 4</li>
<li>sample 7</li>
<li>sample 8</li>
<li>sample 9</li>
<li>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</li>
<li>sample 11</li>
<li>sample 12</li>
<li>sample 13</li>
<li>sample 14</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {width:400px;}
ul li {width:196px;float:left;border:1px solid blue;height:100%;}
```

I'm having gaps above and under, How can I make it without gaps?
here is a sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XgUYf/)

Answer (score 0):

Give some fixed height, say for eg, height: 40px;

Comment: tried that but made gaps much bigger, need to squeeze all of it

Answer (score 0):

The border of the ride side of list is causing the gap since:

- Border is outside of the element client area and has its own layout space. So an element with a border would take more space than one without a border.
- The number of list item on the right side is greater than the left side. So the total space (the total height) of the right side list is greater than the left one.

To solve it, a negative `margin` can be used to compensate the layout space used by the borders. Below is the CSS for the relevant changes:

```
ul li {width:196px;float:left;border:1px solid blue;margin:-1px;height:100%;}
```

Comment: thanks but sample 9 and sample 11 still have a gap :-)

sorry I am not very good at this